# \usepackage{graphicx} prevents change in document

Tags: graphics

I use `\usepackage{graphicx}`. If I change something in my `tex` document and convert it to pdf, my pdf document doesn't change, without `\usepackage{graphicx}` it works.

When I type something like (see below) the word `picture.png` appears instead of the picture.

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setlength
{\parindent}
{0pt}

\oddsidemargin = 20pt
\textwidth = 420pt

\setlength
{\parskip}
{1.5ex}

%body
\begin{document}
text
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{picture.png}
\end{figure}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file `picture.png` does exist in the same folder as your `tex` file?

Comment: Yes, I checked it more then 5 times.

Comment: Run `pdflatex` instead of `latex`.

Comment: @Jake -- yes, this is indeed a duplicate, but the op inserted an example in this version rather than updating the other one, so the question here is "better".  if i were closing, i'd close the earlier one, not this one -- but not voting yet, since only one should be closed, and it's not clear to me how to do that.  flagging for moderator.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE, by the way!

Comment: Verify that you have the file picture.png in the same folder as your main file. The latest version of pdflatex will treat missing pictures as if you were using the draft option.